# I am learning objects and classes in python and i've tried to write a program which requires me print features of animals at different ladder rungs

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

There is a ladder. On the 3rd rung of the ladder is a monkey, the 5th rung has a squirrel, the 8th rung has a pigeon, the 15th rung has an eagle, the 17th rung has another monkey.

The monkey has 2 eyes, 2 hands, 2 legs. The squirrel has 2 eyes, 4 legs. The pigeon has 2 eyes, 2 wings, 2 legs and can fly. The eagle has 2 eyes, 2 wings, 2 legs and can fly.

I have divided the code into two modules ladder-user and ladderutils

ladder-user.py 
To print animal features

```
 from ladderutils import ladder 

    l = ladder()
    print (l.animal_at_rung(3))
    print (l.animal_at_rung(5))
    print (l.animal_at_rung(8))
    print (l.animal_at_rung(15))
    print (l.animal_at_rung(10))
    print (l.get_animals_count())
    print (l.animal_at_rung(3) == l.animal_at_rung(17))
    print (type(l.animal_at_rung(3)) == type(l.animal_at_rung(17)))
    print (l.animal_at_rung(8).fly())
    print (l.animal_at_rung(3).fly())
    print (l.hop(3))
    print (l.animal_at_rung(3))
    print (l.animal_at_rung(4))
    print (l.hop(4))
    print (l.animal_at_rung(4))
```

ladderutils.py

```
class Animal(object):
  features= {}

  def __init__(self,eyes,legs,hands,wings,fly):
    self.features['eyes'] = eyes
    self.features['legs'] = legs
    self.features['hands'] = hands
    self.features['wings'] = wings
    self.features['fly'] = fly

  def fly(self):
    return self.features['fly']

class Monkey(Animal):

  def __init__(self,eyes,legs,hands):
    self.name = 'Monkey'
    Animal.__init__(self,eyes,legs,hands,0,False)

  def __repr__(self):
    temp = {}
    for key in self.features:
        if(self.features[key]>0 and self.features[key]!=False):
            temp[key] = self.features[key]
    return str({self.name:temp})

class Squirrel(Animal):

  def __init__(self,eyes,legs):
    self.name = 'Squirrel'
    Animal.__init__(self,eyes,legs,0,0,False)        

  def __repr__(self):
    temp = {}
    for key in self.features:
        if(self.features[key]>0 or self.features[key]!=False):
            temp[key] = self.features[key]
    return str({self.name:temp})

class Pigeon(Animal):

  def __init__(self,eyes,legs,wings):
    self.name = 'Pigeon'
    Animal.__init__(self,eyes,legs,0,wings,True)

  def __repr__(self):
    print(self.features)
    temp = {}
    for key in self.features:
        if(self.features[key]>0 or self.features[key]==True):
            temp[key] = self.features[key]
    return str({self.name:temp})

class Eagle(Animal):

  def __init__(self,eyes,legs,wings):
    self.name = 'Eagle'
    Animal.__init__(self,eyes,legs,0,wings,True)

  def __repr__(self):
    temp = {}
    for key in self.features:
        if(self.features[key]!=0 and self.features[key]!=False):
            temp[key] = self.features[key]
    return str({self.name:temp})

class ladder:
  ladder_pos = {}


  def __init__(self):
    self.ladder_pos['3'] = Monkey(2,2,2)
    self.ladder_pos['5'] = Squirrel(2,4)
    self.ladder_pos['8'] = Pigeon(2,2,2)
    self.ladder_pos['15'] = Eagle(2,2,2)
    self.ladder_pos['17'] = Monkey(2,2,2)

  def animal_at_rung(self,pos):
    if(str(pos) in self.ladder_pos):
      return self.ladder_pos[str(pos)]
    else:
      return ('None')

  def get_animals_count(self):
    return len(self.ladder_pos)

  def hop(self,pos):
    if(str(pos+1) in self.ladder_pos):
      return ("Not Empty")
    else:
      self.ladder_pos[str(pos+1)] = self.ladder_pos[str(pos)]
      del self.ladder_pos[str(pos)]
      return ('None')
```

My output is

```
{'Monkey': {'legs': 2, 'wings': 2, 'fly': True, 'eyes': 2}}
{'Squirrel': {'legs': 2, 'wings': 2, 'fly': True, 'eyes': 2}}
{'hands': 0, 'legs': 2, 'fly': True, 'wings': 2, 'eyes': 2}
{'Piegon': {'legs': 2, 'wings': 2, 'fly': True, 'eyes': 2}}
{'Eagle': {'legs': 2, 'wings': 2, 'fly': True, 'eyes': 2}}
None
4
False
False
True
True
None
None
{'Monkey': {'legs': 2, 'wings': 2, 'fly': True, 'eyes': 2}}
Not Empty
{'Monkey': {'legs': 2, 'wings': 2, 'fly': True, 'eyes': 2}}
```

But I am supposed to get

```
Monkey <eyes: 2, legs: 2, hands: 2>
Squirrel <eyes: 2, legs: 4>
Pigeon <fly: True, eyes: 2, legs: 2, wings: 2>
Eagle <fly: True, eyes: 2, legs: 2, wings: 2>
None
5
False
True
True
False
None
None
Monkey <eyes: 2, legs: 2, hands: 2>
Not empty
Monkey <eyes: 2, legs: 2, hands: 2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
class Animal(object):
  features= {}

  def __init__(self,eyes,legs,hands,wings,fly):
    self.features['eyes'] = eyes
    self.features['legs'] = legs
    self.features['hands'] = hands
    self.features['wings'] = wings
    self.features['fly'] = fly
```

`features` is a class attribute which is shared amongst all instances of `Animal`. So each time you instanciate `Animal` (or a subclass of), you overwrite the values set by the previous instance. What you want is to make `features` an instance attribute instead:

```
class Animal(object):

  def __init__(self,eyes,legs,hands,wings,fly):
    self.features = {
        'eyes': eyes,
        'legs': legs,
        'hands': hands,
        'wings': wings,
        'fly': fly
        }
```

Also, you copy-pasted the `__repr__` method in each and any subclass while you could just define it in `Animal` - and you could actually simplify it quite a bit:

```
class Animal(object):
  def __init__(self,eyes,legs,hands,wings,fly):
    self.features = {
        'eyes': eyes,
        'legs': legs,
        'hands': hands,
        'wings': wings,
        'fly': fly
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        temp = ", ".join(
            "{}: {}".format(k, v) 
            for k, v in self.features.items() if v
            )
        return "{} <{}>".format(self.name, temp)
```

There are a couple other issues - another class attribute in the `ladder` class (which should be named `Ladder` according to Python naming conventions), using strings keys in `ladder.ladder_pos` then in methods acting on it using integers arguments and converting them to strings again and again (hint: you could just use integers as keys) etc..., but those shouldn't prevent your code from producing the expected outputs.

Comment: Thank you. It has increased my understanding of the topic.

Comment: @AjaySingh glad I could help. And feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)